# Could anyone explain how len() function work internally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm interested in how the `len()` function works internally (how it is implemented) with python3.

Could anyone help-me?

Comment: [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/) is open source software. Enlighten yourself!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not that interesting. It simply calls the `__len__` method of the object.

If you are asking about the specific implementation of `__len__` in the built-in `list`, then it is even less interesting. `list` instances keep their length in an attribute (at least in CPython) to save the need of iteration (hence making `len(list)` an O(1) rather than O(n) operation).

CPython:

```
static Py_ssize_t
list_length(PyListObject *a)
{
    return Py_SIZE(a);
}
```

`Py_SIZE` is defined as a macro

```c
#define Py_SIZE(ob) (_PyVarObject_CAST(ob)->ob_size)
```

So, `len(list)` simply fetches the `ob_size` attribute of the underlying C object/struct.